# How to stop my notification bar from constantly scrolling down?

Tags: notification-bar, samsung-galaxy-a20

Whenever I am viewing some word document or PDF or the Instagram chat in my Samsung A20 phone, the notification bar automatically scrolls down even when it does not have any notification.

Even the "finger sensor gestures" (open and close the notification panel using the fingerprint sensor) have been turned off in my settings.

Please help me to solve this problem.